# c# 8 switch expression not "smart" enough

Tags: switch-statement, c#-8.0, switch-expression

This code is simple, just a normal switch:

```
bool? isSomething = strSomething switch
{
    "I" => true,
    "D" => false,
    _   => null,
};
```

However, the compiler gives me the following error:

> CS0037    Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type

The variable is clearly a nullable bool `bool?`, why can't c# compiler figure this out without me having to cast the null to get it to work:

```
_   => (bool?)null,
```

Am I not getting this right? isn't the cast unnecessary?

Comment: Because expressions in general aren't target-typed. `condition ? 1 : null` fails as well. It's not a trivial matter either, what if the expression was embedded in a larger expression? What would be the correct type then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an opened [issue #2387](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2387) for this in c# lang. Which could be fixed in [this candidate](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/33) for c# 9.